# Amazon S3 sdk and Eclipse - Eclipse not recognizing exceptions?

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-s3

I've recently begun playing around with the Amazon S3 storage solutions. I'm using the Java SDK and just doing some basic things like storing/retrieving files. This works with no problems. I am running into a slight curiosity that confuses me though.

For the [AmazonS3.putObject(String,String,File)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) method, the javadoc implies that the call can throw an AmazonClientException or an AmazonServiceException. So for example

```
//Note: logger is a log4j logger, myBucketName is a String, and s3 is an AmazonS3Client object.
//All are declared and initialized prior to this point.
public void storeToS3(String key, File f) {
  logger.debug("Trying to store " + f.getAbsolutePath());
  s3.putObject(myBucketName, key, f);

}
```

I'm using Eclipse as my IDE, and I would have expected it to start throwing errors since I haven't handled the potential exceptions for the putObject call. I don't think this is because I have those errors turned 'off' (i.e. tell Eclipse to not flag them), since I get similar errors for more 'normal' exceptions (IOException, FileNotFoundException, etc.)

I'm just using the awe-java-sdk-1.9.3.jar on my buildpath/classpath in eclipse and I did not install the Eclipse specific plugin for S3.

Anyone have any idea why Eclipse is not flagging this? I'm using Eclipse Juno Service Release 2. It's not a huge deal, more of a curiosity, but I'm worried if I'm potentially missing other exceptions due to this. I've done some prior digging via 'the Google' but am not coming up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `AmazonClientException` and `AmazonServiceException` are derived from [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html?is-external=true).

From the Javadoc for `RuntimeException`:

> A method is not required to declare in its throws clause any
>   subclasses of RuntimeException that might be thrown during the
>   execution of the method but not caught.

Comment: Ugh, my bad. Sometimes the simplest things escape our notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They both extend `RuntimeException`, so you don't need to catch them. It's just a helpful note that you might want to catch them (since you don't need to declare them in the `throws` clause).